# How to move data from a list to a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, automationstudio

I need to create a automation that extracts and drops a entire list onto the FTP each day.

My issue is that the data lies within a list.

Is it possible to create a query that populates a data extension with the contents of a list?

If this isn't possible are there other options?

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tony is correct. Just to add to this, for Enterprise 2.0 accounts (which current editions fall under) you can access the _EnterpriseAttribute data view to return the custom profile attributes for the subscribers on the list:

[**Data View: EnterpriseAttribute**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_enterpriseattribute)

Sample usage would be along these lines:

```
SELECT
  l.SubscriberKey,
  l.Status,
  e.MyProfileAttribute1,
  e.MyProfileAttribute2
FROM
  _ListSubscribers l WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
  _EnterpriseAttribute e WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON  l.SubscriberID = e._SubscriberID
WHERE
  l.ListID = 123456
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew!
So "e.MyProfileAttribute1" would just be whatever the name of the fields under "Profile Management" for lists are?

Comment: Yes. There's no abstraction or obfuscation. "MyProfileAttribute1" is just the name of the profile attribute - exactly as you see it in the UI.

Answer (score 5):

You **can** query a list, but only the default/out of the box fields, noted below:

[**Data View: ListSubscribers**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_listsubscribers/)

Any additional/custom fields within a list would not be returned and/or your query would fail when referencing list field names that are not noted within the help documentation linked above.

In that case, the extract and import based automation you originally noted is the alternative.  This documentation will help guide you to make the most appropriate selections for your data extract (tracking extract type) needs:

[**Using Tracking Extracts**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/extract_types/tracking_extract/using_tracking_extracts/)

Comment: Thanks Tony! I'd need the custom fields as well. 
Forgive what may be a silly question but to setup a "tracking extract" does a send have to occur to this list or if I just tick "Include All List Members" will it include all lists in this Business Unit?

Comment: My pleasure!  You've got it exactly right - if you check that box it would then include all records, even those not sent to in the period specified.  It would also include all lists (sent to or not) but if you check "Extract Lists" you should be able to filter the output by the ListID or Name columns.

http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/extract_types/tracking_extract/tracking_extract_output/lists/

Comment: Okay excellent. Thanks again Tony. That's working perfectly now.