# SQL Query Error: An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Error while processing square brackets

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I am writing a Query where I want to select subscribers from a list wit the values that are added through a form, however I get the following error: "An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Error while processing square brackets"

This is the Query:

```
Select
l.EmailAddress,
l.First_Name,
l.Last_Name,
l.Company,
l.Phone,
l.userIp,
l.disclaimerTerms,
l.timeStamp,
from [_ListSubscribers] l
where ListName = ‘Whitepaper_Download_Test'
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Does anyone know how to fix the error?

Comment: On top of syntax issues, the _ListSubscribers data view doesn't hold profile attributes. So none of those fields with the exception of EmailAddress are valid. You will need to join with the _EnterpriseAttribute data view and pull the fields from there

Comment: Hi @AnonWonderer, thanks for your suggestion. Do you have a recommendation on how to write this Query?

Comment: Hey Daan - this thread should help: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159582/how-to-move-data-from-a-list-to-a-data-extension

Answer (score 1):

You had a ',' character after last column (l.timeStamp - it needs to be removed). I only use square brackets if there's a space in Data Extension name, otherwise they are not needed.

```
Select
l.EmailAddress,
l.First_Name,
l.Last_Name,
l.Company,
l.Phone,
l.userIp,
l.disclaimerTerms,
l.timeStamp
from _ListSubscribers l
where ListName = 'Whitepaper_Download_Test'
```

Comment: thanks for you suggestion, I thinks it may be something else, because I still receive the same error. Can it be the '_' in ListName?

Comment: @Mateusz "I only use square brackets if there's a space in Data Extension name, otherwise they are not needed." This is wrong. I had a Dataextension starting with 000_ and the syntax always crashed until i put brackets around it.

Answer (score 0):

You got a wrong character in the where clause

```
where ListName = ‘Whitepaper_Download_Test'
```

Should be

```
where ListName = 'Whitepaper_Download_Test'
```

and after the l.timeStamp, should not be a comma.

==>

```
Select
l.EmailAddress,
l.First_Name,
l.Last_Name,
l.Company,
l.Phone,
l.userIp,
l.disclaimerTerms,
l.timeStamp
from [_ListSubscribers] l
where ListName = 'Whitepaper_Download_Test'
```

Let us assume you have the List Whitepaper_Download_Test and a dataextension B that has these fields: Email,First,Last,Comp,Phone,Ip,Terms,Time. (I changed to different fields that you get the point).

```
Select
l.EmailAddress AS Email,
l.First_Name AS First,
l.Last_Name AS Last,
l.Company AS Comp,
l.Phone AS Phone,
l.userIp AS Ip,
l.disclaimerTerms AS Terms,
l.timeStamp AS Time
from [_ListSubscribers] l
where ListName = 'Whitepaper_Download_Test'
```

Target Data Extension is B.

But i believe that doesnt fix your First_Name error. Are you sure it is in the List? Can you make a Screenshot of the Fields in that List(no values please)?

Just for reference: Here is the description of _ListSubscribers https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_listsubscribers.htm&type=5

Comment: If this doesnt work, maybe erase the brackets and write `from _ListSubscribers AS l`

Comment: Hi @Johannes, Thanks a lot for your help. I am now receiving the following error  Invalid column name 'First_Name'. This is my first time writing a Query so I'm not sure how to move forward from here. I can confirm dat First_Name in my Attributes is also First_Name. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain what you are going to do with the query? I believe I haven’t really understood your use case. Do you want to query this data from the list and store it into another data extension or what’s the plan.

Comment: of course! So I am using WebCollect to store subscribers on a list. I want to add these subscribers to Salesforce through Journey Builder. I am not able to use the API, otherwise I could send people straight away to the data extension. So this is why I want to Query the people who are on a list and add them to a data extension, which I will use as a starting point for the Journey.

Comment: Edited my answer. But i believe we need more and precise information from your end